# Considering quotes and few special characters in string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to execute the below command in remote servers..

> find /usr/nsh/NSH/Transactions/log -name "bldeploy-*" -and  -printf
>   '%T@:%p\n' | sort -V | sed -r 's/^[^:]+://'|xargs egrep -i
>   "VANTAGE_CORE-APP"|tail -1|cut -d '"' -f2

how can i put this single command in string??? 
I have trying this way but its not working.

```
Dim str as string  = "-above command-"
```

Can anyone let me know, how can place this whole command in one string considering all quotes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like VB.NET, you simply need to escape the double quotes (`"` --> `""`).

Like so:

```
Dim str as string = "find /usr/nsh/NSH/Transactions/log -name ""bldeploy-*"" -and -printf '%T@:%p\n' | sort -V | sed -r 's/^[^:]+://'|xargs egrep -i ""VANTAGE_CORE-APP""|tail -1|cut -d '""' -f2"
```